# Apply SQL Server Management Studio code editor scripts to SQL Server Developer edition using liquibase

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, liquibase

I'm running
[SQL Server 2019 developer edition in linux Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) and I would like to apply to it some SQL scripts. I'm using [liquibase cli](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/cli/home.html) to do that. The only driver I downloaded for that purpose is [mssql jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/8.2.2.jre13/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre13.jar). Liquibase changelog is in yaml format and consists of a long list of includes of mentioned SQL scripts. When launching `liquibase update`, the failure occurs on SQL validation, complaining on

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. [Failed SQL: (102) USE [arbitrary_db_name]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = N'arbitrary_schema_name')
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'CREATE SCHEMA [arbitrary_schema_name]'
GO]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:430)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:87)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:159)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1276)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1258)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:622)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:872)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:767)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3053)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:743)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:426)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way of applying existing scripts in described scenario without rewriting them to not include some of MS SQL Server Management Studio constructs like batch grouping `GO` command?

Comment: Remove the `GO` from your script. It's not a SQL command and can only be used in tools supporting that as a delimiter. But for a complete answer you will have to show us your changeset

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks. There are 5000 files to apply. Yes, removing `GO` helps. However, presumably not being the only `T-SQL` construct to be problematic,  I am looking for a solution that could either convert `T-SQL` to plain `SQL` on the fly or could otherwise apply `T-SQL` to `MS SQL Server`.

Comment: "*apply T-SQL to MS SQL Server*" makes no sense. T-SQL **is** SQL Server's dialect. There is nothing to convert. But `GO` isn't T-SQL to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That shows how poorly I am familiar with the subject. I will try to correct my question. Thanks!